# Can an external application start ArcCatalog.exe and immediately navigate to a specific folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, command-line

I'm looking something similar to explorer's command line switches:
`explorer.exe /select,c:\examples\condensed\need\obtains\dispute\under\billion\floor`

or

`explorer.exe /e,c:\examples\condensed\need\obtains\dispute\under\billion\floor`

Can an external application create a folder `c:\examples\condensed\need\obtains\dispute\under\billion\floor` and then start ArcCatalog.exe in that location?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you explained why you want this particular functionality, alternatives could be suggested. I personally don't have any use case in mind for this that couldn't be accomplished by other means.

Comment: After a file geodb is created (via a custom wizard), the user has to copy/paste the path into ArcCatalog. So this is a convenience function only (and optional because users don't always choose to view).